# Error executing 'AUTHENTICATE' task on 'serveradmin' USER" with a stack trace including System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException

Tags: windows-server-2016

I am trying to log in to the SolidCP panel with the serveradmin account, but I'm getting the following error message:

> Server Error in '/' Application.
> System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: Server was unable to process request. ---> System.Exception: Error executing 'AUTHENTICATE' task on 'serveradmin' USER ---> System.Exception: Error executing 'AUTHENTICATE' task on 'serveradmin' USER ---> System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException: The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure.
> at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartSendAuthResetSignal(ProtocolToken message, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest, Exception exception)
> at System.Net.Security.SslState.CheckCompletionBeforeNextReceive(ProtocolToken message, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
> at System.Net.Security.SslState.ProcessReceivedBlob(Byte[] buffer, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
> at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartReceiveBlob(Byte[] buffer, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
> at System.Net.Security.SslState.CheckCompletionBeforeNextReceive(ProtocolToken message, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
> at System.Net.Security.SslState.ProcessReceivedBlob(Byte[] buffer, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
> at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartReceiveBlob(Byte[] buffer, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
> at System.Net.Security.SslState.CheckCompletionBeforeNextReceive(ProtocolToken message, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
> at System.Net.Security.SslState.ProcessReceivedBlob(Byte[] buffer, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
> at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartReceiveBlob(Byte[] buffer, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
> at System.Net.Security.SslState.CheckCompletionBeforeNextReceive(ProtocolToken message, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
> at System.Net.Security.SslState.ForceAuthentication(Boolean receiveFirst, Byte[] buffer, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest, Boolean renegotiation)
> at System.Net.Security.SslState.ProcessAuthentication(LazyAsyncResult lazyResult)
> at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
> at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
> at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
> at System.Net.TlsStream.ProcessAuthentication(LazyAsyncResult result)
> at System.Net.TlsStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
> at System.Net.PooledStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
> at System.Net.Mail.SmtpConnection.Flush()
> at System.Net.Mail.ReadLinesCommand.Send(SmtpConnection conn)
> at System.Net.Mail.EHelloCommand.Send(SmtpConnection conn, String domain)
> at System.Net.Mail.SmtpConnection.GetConnection(ServicePoint servicePoint)
> at System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.GetConnection()
> at System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.Send(MailMessage message)
> at SolidCP.EnterpriseServer.MailHelper.SendMessage(String from, String to, String bcc, String subject, String body, MailPriority priority, Boolean isHtml, Attachment[] attachments)
> at SolidCP.EnterpriseServer.UserController.SendVerificationCode(String username)
> End of inner exception stack trace ---
> at SolidCP.EnterpriseServer.UserController.SendVerificationCode(String username)
> at SolidCP.EnterpriseServer.UserController.AuthenticateUser(String username, String password, String ip)
> End of inner exception stack trace ---
> at SolidCP.EnterpriseServer.UserController.AuthenticateUser(String username, String password, String ip)
> at SolidCP.EnterpriseServer.esAuthentication.AuthenticateUser(String username, String password, String ip)
> End of inner exception stack trace ---
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: Server was unable to process request. ---> System.Exception: Error executing 'AUTHENTICATE' task on 'serveradmin' USER ---> System.Exception: Error executing 'AUTHENTICATE' task on 'serveradmin' USER ---> System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException: The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure.
> at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartSendAuthResetSignal(ProtocolToken message, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest, Exception exception)
> at System.Net.Security.SslState.CheckCompletionBeforeNextReceive(ProtocolToken message, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
> at System.Net.Security.SslState.ProcessReceivedBlob(Byte[] buffer, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
> at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartReceiveBlob(Byte[] buffer, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
> at System.Net.Security.SslState.CheckCompletionBeforeNextReceive(ProtocolToken message, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
> at System.Net.Security.SslState.ProcessReceivedBlob(Byte[] buffer, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
> at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartReceiveBlob(Byte[] buffer, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
> at System.Net.Security.SslState.CheckCompletionBeforeNextReceive(ProtocolToken message, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
> at System.Net.Security.SslState.ProcessReceivedBlob(Byte[] buffer, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
> at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartReceiveBlob(Byte[] buffer, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
> at System.Net.Security.SslState.CheckCompletionBeforeNextReceive(ProtocolToken message, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
> at System.Net.Security.SslState.ForceAuthentication(Boolean receiveFirst, Byte[] buffer, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest, Boolean renegotiation)
> at System.Net.Security.SslState.ProcessAuthentication(LazyAsyncResult lazyResult)
> at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
> at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
> at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
> at System.Net.TlsStream.ProcessAuthentication(LazyAsyncResult result)
> at System.Net.TlsStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
> at System.Net.PooledStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
> at System.Net.Mail.SmtpConnection.Flush()
> at System.Net.Mail.ReadLinesCommand.Send(SmtpConnection conn)
> at System.Net.Mail.EHelloCommand.Send(SmtpConnection conn, String domain)
> at System.Net.Mail.SmtpConnection.GetConnection(ServicePoint servicePoint)
> at System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.GetConnection()
> at System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.Send(MailMessage message)
> at SolidCP.EnterpriseServer.MailHelper.SendMessage(String from, String to, String bcc, String subject, String body, MailPriority priority, Boolean isHtml, Attachment[] attachments)
> at SolidCP.EnterpriseServer.UserController.SendVerificationCode(String username)
> End of inner exception stack trace ---
> at SolidCP.EnterpriseServer.UserController.SendVerificationCode(String username)
> at SolidCP.EnterpriseServer.UserController.AuthenticateUser(String username, String password, String ip)
> End of inner exception stack trace ---
> at SolidCP.EnterpriseServer.UserController.AuthenticateUser(String username, String password, String ip)
> at SolidCP.EnterpriseServer.esAuthentication.AuthenticateUser(String username, String password, String ip)
> End of inner exception stack trace ---

What could be causing this error and how can I resolve it?

I am trying to log in to the SolidCP panel with the serveradmin account, but I'm getting the following error message